# Get parameters from another component

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla3.2

I have two custom components that reference an external database.  In component1 I set the parameters necessary to connect to that external DB.

Is there I way that I can use the parameter set in component1 within component2?

my code within my model in component2:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$params = $app->getParams('com_component1');
```

advises me of a fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method JApplicationAdministrator::getParams() in /var/www....
```

Should I just stop being lazy and redefine the same parameters in component2, or is there a reasonable solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the following code.

```
$params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_component1');
$test = $params->get('param_name');
```

To get parameters, you need to use `JComponentHelper`, not `JFactory`.

Comment: Merci, Danke, and Thanks!